# Chrome message passing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is not a real extension, I'm just screwing around to see how this works.

Basically, in my background.html page I have this:

```
function test3()
{
alert("blah3");
chrome.extension.sendRequest('test2');
}
```

and in my popup.html page, I have this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.function == "test3") {
           alert("Works!");
           }
    }
);
```

But the alert "Works" never seems to be called...
I even tried to replace the

```
 alert("Works!");
```

with 
call_test_function();

which in turn has an alert()... but that does not get called either.

Mind telling me where I went wrong? And giving me the code to make my little example work?

Thanks!
R

EDIT:
I reversed it, now my code is as below:

---

Manifest:

```
  "name": "RyanTest for Chrome",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Ryan testing messaging!",
     "background_page": "mf_background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "pop_mf.html"
```

mf_background

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.style3 {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.style4 {
    font-size: x-small;
}
.style5 {
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
</style><script>
var b="100";
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.function == "test2") {
           alert("Works!");
           console.log("This is in popup!");
           }
    }
);


</script>


</head>
```

pop_mf

```
<html><head><style>
body {
  min-width:357px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}


</style>

<script>
// <!--

function test3()
{
//alert(b);
chrome.extension.sendRequest('test2');
}


test3();
// -->
</script></head><body>RyanTEST
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alerts don't work in popups. Use `console.log` instead.

Also instead of `if(request.function == "test3")` it should be `if(request == "test2")` perhaps (and popup must be opened at this moment)

Comment: ok, changed test3 to test2, and deleted the alert and added this "console.log("This is in popup!");" but when I right click on the popup button and inspect popup... there is nothing in the console :(

Comment: @Ryan Are you sure that popup remains open when request is being sent from background page?

Comment: @serg, not sure... because I click the inspect popup,and I see the console... but then to fire the backgroud page I have to click the "reload" link in the extensions page... which closes the popup.

Don't know how else to do it...

Comment: @Ryan In this case your workflow is probably not correct. You can't send a request to a popup page if it is closed. If you need some data in the popup page then maybe you need to send the request FROM popup TO background page instead? (you might even don't need a request as you can access background page variables directly)

Comment: @serg, Ok, I reversed it. I put the code from the popup into the background and the background's code into popup... nothing :(

Comment: @Ryan Please copy your latest code into the original question.

Comment: @serg, also how do you mean "you can access backgroun page variables directly"? I declared a "var b = 100;" in the background and had an "alert(b);"  in the popup... but that just throws an error

Comment: @Ryan As I said alerts don't work in popups. To access var `a` from popup you need to call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().a`

Comment: @serg, Ok, edited the main box on top... As you can see I moved the alert from the popup... and thanks for the "chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().a" now I understand that!

Comment: @Ryan Why do you write `request.function == "test2"`? It should be `request == "test2"`, I pointed it out right in the original answer.

Comment: @serg, so you did! I have no idea why I missed that...and it works! Which closes this thread, thank you so much for your help!